# Using D3js to make a line that beyond some point turns dashed

Tags: d3.js

I construct the "var cities" in such a way that beyond "some_date" the "at" turns from "0" to "1". Then I try to use this information to draw a line that beyond "some_date" turns dashed. Could please someone tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
 return {
  name: name,
  values: data.map(function(d) {
   if(d.date < some_date){
    return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name], vis:"0", at:"0"};
   }else{
    return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name], vis:"0", at:"1"};
   };
  })
 };
});

city.append("path")
 .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("d", function(d) {if(d.name.match(/pib_1t/)){
  d.vis = "1";
  return line(d.values);
 }})
 .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
 .style("stroke-dasharray", function(d){
  console.log(d.name);
  d.values.forEach(function(e, i) {
   if(e.at == "1"){
    return ("2,2");
   }else{
    return ("2,0");
   };
 });
});
```

Well, I tried to use a "custom line generator" but I got an ugly result. So I solved the problem constructing two lines. The first one goes until "some_date" is reached and is a normal line. The second is a dashed line and it starts at "some_date". See the code bellow.

```
// first line

city.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {if(d.name.match(/pib_1t/)){
    d.vis = "1";
    return line(d.values.slice(0,[bisect(data,some_date)]));
  }})
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

// second line

city.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", ("2, 2"))
  .attr("d", function(d) {if(d.name.match(/pib_1t/)){
    d.vis = "1";
    return line(d.values.slice([bisect(data, some_date)-1],data.length));
  }})
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Comment: I don't think that the d.values.forEach is needed honestly. If you use directly a function (d) with the if statement in the dasharray it should be fine

Comment: You can't do it this way, you need several lines or a custom line generator (see e.g. [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/wd/)).